# Javascript function:signup() not sumbitting to ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

New to Ajax and starting up with Javascript and jQuery.

I have a form that ends with a submit button, JavaScript through a set `function signup(){` will validate fields and other requirements. All up to here is good. Yet once all processes correctly and I get to the end, where the Javascript should send the information over to Ajax for validation and inserting into the database: at this point the link doesn't work and I get an error telling me `AjaxObj` isn't defined. I know this belongs to a certain ajax js library that I can't seem to find. If I'm not mistaken, this is similar if not the same Xttp processing - but I'm not sure how this would apply here.

On my js side I have the following on the last else statement of the signup function:

```
$("#signupbtn").css("display","none");
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'Processing...'; // up to here all OK //

                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                var ajax = xhttp.open("POST", "FLClubRegisterAction.php", true);
                ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                        if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                            $("#signupbtn").css("display","block");
                        } else {
                            window.scrollTo(0,0);
                            document.getElementById("signupform").innerHTML = "Congratulations "+fname+" "+lname+", you are one step closer to activating your account. We have sent you an email containing an activation link. It is required that you follow this link in order to enable your online access. Thank you!";
                        }
                    }
                };
                ajax.send("username="+username+"&email="+email+"&password="+password+"&prefix="+prefix+"&fname="+fname+"&mname="+mname+"&lname="+lname+"&gender="+gender+"&dob="+dob+"&address1="+address1+"&address2="+address2+"&city="+city+"&state="+state+"&zip="+zip+"&secquest1="+secquest1+"&secansw1="+secansw1+"&emailpromo="+emailpromo);
            }
```

The PHP code is:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("/US/en/local/ressources/php/connection.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $prefix = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['prefix']);
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['fname']);
    $mname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['mname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['lname']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['gender']);
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['dob']);
    $address1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address1']);
    $address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['address2']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['city']);
    $state = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['state']);
    $zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['zip']);
    $secquest1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['secquest1']);
    $secansw1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['secansw1']);
    $emailpromo = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['emailpromo']);
    $accountactive = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['accountactive']);

    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT accnum FROM FLCUsers WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $username_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT accnum FROM FLCUsers WHERE email='$email' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $email_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($username == "" || $email == "" || $confemail == "" || $password == "" || $confpassword == "" || $fname == "" || $lname == "" || $gender == "" || $address1 == "" || $city == "" || $state == "" || $zip == "" || $secquest1 == "" || $secansw1 == ""){
        echo "All required fields have not been completed";
        exit();
    } else if ($username_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username selected is already taken.";
        exit();
    } else if ($email_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo "Your username must contain 5 to 40 caracters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt

        $res = explode("/", $dob);
        $dobok = $res[2]."-".$res[0]."-".$res[1];

        $cryptpass = crypt($password);
        include_once ("/US/en/local/ressources/php/randStrGen.php");
        $password_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO FLCUsers (username, email, password, prefix, fname, mname, lname, gender, dob, address1, address2, city, state, zip, secquest1, secansw1, creationip, signupdate, laslogin, accountactive)       
                VALUES('$username','$email','$password_hash','$prefix','$fname','$mname','$lname','$gender', '$dobok', $address1','$address2','$city','$state','$zip','$mname','$secansw1','$secansw1','$ip',now(),now(), 0)";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $accnum = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (accnum, username, background) VALUES ('$accnum','$username','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("FLCUsers/$username")) {
            mkdir("FLCUsers/$username", 0755);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
    exit();
}
```

Thank you for any tips anyone would be so kind as to share !

Comment: Java != JavaScript...

Comment: Set the content type xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: what is `if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {`

Comment: It would that if there is a error response from the PHP then the submit button would appear again and the error message would be displayed on the span that has #status... and otherwise it would replace the entire form with the success message... Is this completely wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use this jQuery indeed:

```
$.ajax({
                    url: "/US/en/local/flclub/account/action/FLClubRegisterAction.php",
                    data: dataToSend,
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(data, status) {
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(status);
                        if(data.code == 400 || data.code == 401 || data.code == 402 || data.code ==403){
                            //alert('error');
                            $('#status').html('Error...' + data.message);
                            $("#signupbtn").css("display","block")
                        }
```

and for the error handling you would want to use something that resembles:

```
if ($username_check > 0){ 

        echo json_encode(["message"=>"The username selected is already taken.", "code"=>400]);
        exit();
```

This creates the error that will be handled in jQuery and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can send data in Ajax by easier way than this. Why using XMLHttpRequest ?`var dataToSend = {'username': username, 'email': email, 'password': password, ...};
$.ajax({
        url: "FLClubRegisterAction.php",
        data: dataToSend,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
        // Do something in success callback.
        },
        error: function(err){
            // Do something if error.
        }
        });`

Comment: Thank you for your response and time!

I'm getting this in the console : 

ReferenceError: ajax is not defined
error
http://localhost:8888/US/en/local/Ressources/Java/javascript.js:103:16
u
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js:2:27452

Therefore is it maybe my linked library that is wrong or the way it is handling the return. As in this doesn't seem right : 

`error: function(err){
               document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
       $("#signupbtn").css("display","block");
           }`

Comment: ok forget your variable ajax, you don't need it. Your data are sent in dataToSend variable. Your answer will be in data if it's a success or in err if you have a error.

Comment: Remove everything from var xhttp = ...  to ajax.send ... and replace that by my code. For now as i see, you don't coding in jquery, you coding in raw javascript.

Comment: Replace that: document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = 'Processing...'; by $('#status').html('Processing...'); This is jquery way and it's easier and faster.

Comment: Oh okay! And we do agree that my having this is correct : `url: "/US/en/local/flclub/account/action/FLClubRegisterAction.php",` within the `$.ajax{` ? (as it's not located in the same place as all the java and php files